# Is it strict to define $0^0=1$ like this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

From the binomial formula, some idea about the disputable definition $0^0$ came to my mind.

We see from the well-known identity,
$$(1-x)^{-n} =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}x^k.$$
Where if let $x=0$, then $\binom{n-1}{n-1}0^0+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}0^k=0^0=1$.

Is this the strict way of proving $0^0=1$?

Comment: The convention of $x^0$ being the constant $1$ function is the one that works for most manipulations of polynomial identities and power series. This observation of yours is entirely within that general remark.

Comment: But to answer the question you asked:: No, this is not a strict way of "proving" that claim. It's merely an observation that if you want your "well-known identity" to apply to $x = 0$ as well as the values for which it's known to apply (nonzero $x$), then you would need to define $0^0 = 1$. But "what you want" and "what's a proof" are different things.

Comment: $0^0$ is the number of functions from $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$; there is precisely one such: the empty function so $0^0=1$. This follows from the standard definition of exponentiation of cardinal numbers.